# Continuing an already started HTTP call in background in iOS

Tags: ios, http, background, nsurlconnection, task

I perform a synchronous HTTP request to a REST service regularly to get possible data updates for my app. I do the call when the app is active and a timer is finished, this is the code snippet:

```
__block BOOL result;

            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(UpdateQueue, NULL);
            dispatch_async(queue,^{

                UpdateMngr *updateMngr = [[UpdateMngr alloc] init];
                result = [updateMngr getUpdatedData];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (result) {
                        // Notify user update is OK
                    }
                    else {
                        // Notify user update failed
                    }
                });
            });
```

Where the `getUpdatedData` method is:

```
- (BOOL)getUpdatedData
{
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:self.serviceURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData* jsonData = [self getRequestBody];    
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSData *content = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:&response
                                                    error:&error];

if (([content length] > 0) && (error == nil)) {
    id parseResult = [self parseJson:content];

    if ([parseResult isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    else if ([parseResult isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            @try {
                    // Success
                    // Save data in database
            }
            @catch (NSException *ex) {
                    // Handle error
            }
    }
}
else if (([content length] == 0) && (error == nil)) {
    // No updated data
    return NO;
}
else if (error != nil) {
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

It seems that going to background or going to inactive state because, for example, an incoming phone call, the request is interrupted and I see that sometimes the app behaves as if the data I expect to receive from the service is not complete and only a piece of it is shown to the user, despite I've received the response.

I've been reading the [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) section about executing finite-length tasks in background, but I'm not sure how to apply it here, since the code snippet in that document seems to launch the complete task in background, while what I need is to finish an already started task... Should I always perform my task in background, just in case? Or how could I handle this scenario? I guess this should be a quite common scenario, but I don´t find any example or tutorial that enlightens me.

Note: my app works for **iOS 5+**

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** Would this be the appropriate solution?:

```
- (void)getUpdates
{
   self.bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
                // stopped or ending the task outright.
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
                self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }];

   __block BOOL result;

            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(UpdateQueue, NULL);
            dispatch_async(queue,^{

                UpdateMngr *updateMngr = [[UpdateMngr alloc] init];
                result = [updateMngr getUpdatedData];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (result) {
                        // Notify user update is OK
                    }
                    else {
                        // Notify user update failed
                    }
                });
            });

   // Finish background task
            if (self.bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
                self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
}
```

Where `self.bgTask` is `@property UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;`

Comment: You are running your task asynchronously, so you have a whole set of code that runs on a background thread. Starting a 'background' task from the point of view of telling the application about it doesn't mean it will run any differently unless the app looses its status as the foreground app. You see the difference between the multiple meanings of 'background' ?

Comment: @Wain you're right... when I say here `background`, I mean being the app in background (or inactive...)

Comment: You write your code to deal with the app being in the background when appropriate, but you don't need to check that it actually is in the background before creating the task.

Comment: @Wain so, if the task starts and then the app goes to background or inactive state before the task has finished... what should I do?

Comment: You should have written the code such that the background task can continue if the app goes to the background. That means starting the background task before your async process and completing after it has done.

Comment: @Wain to summarize... then there is no need to launch the task in background in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method, right? Is the code I've edited in my question the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close, but it has an issue because the background task is started and then immediately completed (because it's done inside the method, but not inside the async block. Try this:

```
- (void)getUpdates
{
    self.bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
            // stopped or ending the task outright.
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
            self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];

        __block BOOL result;

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(UpdateQueue, NULL);
        dispatch_async(queue,^{

            UpdateMngr *updateMngr = [[UpdateMngr alloc] init];
            result = [updateMngr getUpdatedData];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (result) {
                    // Notify user update is OK
                }
                else {
                    // Notify user update failed
                }

                // Finish background task
                if (self.bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
                    self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                }
            });
        });
}
```